# Regarding Drupal7 User profiles and registeration

Tags: drupal-7, user-profile

on my front page the user registers by typing in his username, email, password..once he clicks submit he log ins and is redirected to his profile edit page (not account settings)..i am able to do that using rules..i am using Profile2 and adding new fields..however i also want the old fields such as username, password,and email id to appear there ... it would be the same password or username and email id that the user entered while registering but i just want to create/display these fields on this edit profile page for completeness.they may have the earlier entered values copied and the user may enter/edit it here again and be able to save (ofcourse he should get an error if he enters a new email id on that page)

what i want is something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iILdp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add fields to exsitng core profile? admin/config/people/accounts/fields .There you can add new fields which will be displayed on user page.

Comment: terms and conditions module, and captcha module. You can mark the fields required or use field validation module.